# Rundeck ssh connection refused

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, rundeck

I can't execute remotely on my nodes, I already stored the node's private key on `/var/lib/rundeck/nodes/backend-01.key` and I get this error:

Execution log:

```
Execution failed: 20 in project deployments: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [backend-01: ConnectionFailure: Conexión rehusada (Connection refused)]}, Node failures: {backend-01=[ConnectionFailure: Conexión rehusada (Connection refused)]}, status: failed]
```

My resources.xml:

```
<project>
  <node name="backend-01"
        description="Backend-01"
        tags=""
        hostname="10.10.10.10"
        osArch=" x86_64"
        osFamily="unix"
        osName="Linux"
        osVersion="x86_64"
        username="backend-01"
        ssh-keypath="/var/lib/rundeck/nodes/backend-01.key"
  />
</project>
```

I store node private key on `/var/lib/rundeck/nodes/backend-01.key`

I followed this tutorial, but didn't worked

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RxNSqprG_BU

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection refused` means the ssh port on target node is not open. This can be firewall policy, openssh is not running and others

Are you be able to ssh from your rundeck server to your target node using `ssh -i /var/lib/rundeck/nodes/backend-01.key backend-01@10.10.10.10`?

Comment: @FranAguiar okay, looks like you have a ssh key issue... https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2 this is be best tutorial on set up ssh

Answer (score 1):

Does your key require a passphrase? If so, see [Rundeck Administration Guide: SSH Private Key Passphrase](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/projects/node-execution/ssh.html#ssh-private-key-passphrase).